# Facebook Graph API - see which of a user's friends of friends also have my app installed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Would it be possible to have an app that returns the friends of friends of the current user that have the app installed? I understand that this may be impossible due to privacy issues, but is there not some sort of requirement that can be imposed when the app is installed to make this information public to everyone and so to the current user?

**EDIT:**

In fact, users will be entered into my own database so what I really need to be able to do is search through all of a user's friends and for each one query whether they have any friends who match a name/id in my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, apps can only access information for friends of the current user, but not for friends of those friends again.

Otherwise, the “operating distance” of an app could be quite huge, without people even knowing what way an app was able to get access to their information (or that it even did get access at all) – look at it this way:

If you do not want to *generally* disallow apps to access some of your info when friends are using them, because it has *some* (social) benefits from your standpoint, but you have this weird guy/girl amongst your friends, who’s using sh*tloads of apps and giving them *friends*-permissions all the time … well, no problem, unfriend him/her, and all’s well. But now let’s say, that guy/girl/dude/whatever is not *directly* friends with you, but only with your younger brother (who you’re FB friends with in this scenario, of course) – you’d have to actually unfriend your *brother* for this to stop … and, not knowing your little brother (or whether you even have one) – I’d still guess this would not be what *most* Facebook users would want.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So through a third party app you can interact with other Facebook users, you're just not allowed to know their degree of separation from you?

Comment: Depends on what exactly you mean by “interact”. An app can maybe comment on stuff for you, post to another user’s wall (if they have their settings set to let you do that), … and some other “normal” stuff you as a user would be able to do directly on facebook.com without using an app at all. But the app will not be able to get any kind of information from other people on your behalf, if you are not directly friends with them.